# Inspect JavaScript behind DIV in Chrome's Inspect Element

Tags: javascript, inspector

I've got a simple close function that closes down a JS popup. The problem is, I don't know where to locate it amongst many many javascript files. 
What's the best way to find it, if I wanted to modify it? I was thinking I could use Chrome's Inspect Element, in the same way as I find CSS - but I am unsure how to do this. Could someone help me out?

Thanks to all

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+F and type what you want to search.

Answer (score 1):

All JS files can be located under `Sources` in the Chrome Developer Tools. If you want to inspect a specific piece code when it runs, you can set the `Break on` options in the HTML inspection panel.